# Android Google Map V2 API results in building error

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been wanting to use the Android Google Map API in an app I've been developing and have had trouble implementing it. I have followed the tutorial provided by Google Developers (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker) and when I came to run the application it resulted in this build-error: [Build Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XefT0.png). I have looked for a way around this but have not been able to find a solution.

activity_maps.xml

```html
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.mapwithmarker.MapsMarkerActivity" />
```

MapsWithMarkerActivity

```
    package com.example.mapwithmarker;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    /**
     * An activity that displays a Google map with a marker (pin) to indicate a particular location.
     */
    public class MapsMarkerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            // Get the SupportMapFragment and request notification
            // when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
            // and move the map's camera to the same location.
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        }
}
```

build.gradle (Module App)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 24
            buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
            defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.mapwithmarker"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            resValue "string", "google_maps_key", 
    (project.findProperty("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") ?: "")
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.mapwithmarker">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

            <activity
                android:name=".MapsMarkerActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

I am using the Nexus 5X API 23 (Android 6.0, API 23) Emulator to run this.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way to get rid of this, just adding the dependency you needed. In your case;

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'`

replace to

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'`

Comment: Hi, that has got the app to build successfully, so thank you for that. I have run into a new error that causes the authentication to fail on server. Do I need to use another API key for this?

Comment: `I have run into a new error that causes the authentication to fail on server` This seems an another problem which is not related to Google Maps. Even if you didn't obtain an api key and also didn't get this `GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY` value in your build gradle, then you will see an blank area instead of map.